# Error moving Sql Server Azure between subscriptions

Tags: azure, sql, azure-sql

I’m trying to move a SQL Azure Server that has 2 databases from one subscription to another. The databases’ sizes are 10G and 1G. I’m using the azure portal to do it and I’m getting the following error ->

There was an error moving resources.

Resources '/subscriptions/f4b0ab63/resourceGroups/rg_asisa/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlasisatools' could not be moved. The tracking Id is xxx (Code: ResourceMoveFailed) Subscription 'f4b0ab63' does not have the server 'sqlasisatools'. (Code: SubscriptionDoesNotHaveServer)

I'm sure I have the Sql Azure server because its on production enviroment.

Comment: You have to move the server and databases altogether.

Comment: Your database and server are in the same resource group?

Comment: Yes, the databases and the server are in the same resource group and also in the same region

Comment: Hi, do you select your sql server and your databases and webapp. If it does not work, I suggest you could open a ticket.

Comment: Hi, where can I open a ticket?

Comment: @Copeleto Sorry for the late reply. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).